# Determine if a specific DateTime is within a time interval using Luxon

Tags: javascript, luxon

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a specific DateTime is within a time interval.  For example, let's say I have a variable named `dateTimeToCheck` and I want to see if it is within the first quarter of the year (Jan 1st to March 31st).

I could use `diff` between `dateTimeToCheck` and Jan 1st and then `diff` between `dateTimeToCheck` and March 31st followed by some calculations, but I feel like there should be a cleaner way using Luxon's `Interval` or something like that.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use Luxon's [`Interval`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#interval). The API has the [`contains`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#intervalcontains) method that:

> Return whether this Interval contains the specified DateTime.

Here an example where I've used [`fromDateTimes`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#intervalfromdatetimes) to create `Interval` object:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const Interval = luxon.Interval;

const interval = Interval.fromDateTimes(DateTime.local(2023, 1, 1), DateTime.local(2023, 3, 31));
let dateTimeToCheck = DateTime.now();
console.log(interval.contains(dateTimeToCheck));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.2.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice!  I can't believe I missed the `contains` method!